# iOS: Custom UITableViewCell from nib without a reuseIdentifier?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that's loaded from a nib. I can pull this into my app with a reuseIdentifier by performing the following steps:

1) Set the reuse identifier in the Nib as "CustomCellIndentifier"

2) Register the nib:

```
[[self tableView] registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellIndentifier"];
```

3) Return the cell in tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellIndentifier"];
     return cell;
}
```

---

**My question is, how can I return a cell WITHOUT a reuse identifier? I have a small table and I don't want the cell to be reused (it messes up some subviews I have in the cell if I scroll).**

I've tried a combination of setting the above 3 reuse identifiers to nil and they all generate errors.

I've also tried this below, but the cell contents reset if I scroll past the cell and I get an error message "no index path for table cell being reused":

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
     if (cell == nil) {
           NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not a good way, but as per your requirement Use this:

Write the `init` method in your `CustomCell` class

```
- (id)init
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QuestionOptionCell" owner:self options:nil];
        CustomCell *theEditView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        self = theEditView;
        theEditView = nil;
        return self
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
     if (cell == nil) {
           NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
           cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
     }

     return cell;
}
```